# Ubuntu 12.10 (32-bit) Sound Dummy Output

Tags: alsa

I am running a Gateway, Model: 566GE, and I installed ubuntu on it.  but the sound is saying dummy output.

here is the !!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.61 Link:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0acb2f3723a9dda3b2c7162d7428d555e1413c65

here is my motherboard info:

myersg@Ubuntu-Gateway:~$ sudo dmidecode -t 2
[sudo] password for myersg:

```
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.3 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 20 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
    Product Name: D915GAG
    Version: AAC77881-306
    Serial Number: BQAG52803232
    Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Base Board Chassis Location
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Unknown
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

myersg@Ubuntu-Gateway:~$ sudo aplay -l

```
** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
```

myersg@Ubuntu-Gateway:~$ lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82915G/P/GV/GL/PL/910GL Memory Controller Hub (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 90100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at ffe0 [size=8]
    Memory at 80000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 90180000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: intelfb, i915

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at 901c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90200000-902fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090600000-00000000907fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90300000-903fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090800000-00000000909fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90400000-904fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090a00000-0000000090bfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90500000-905fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090c00000-0000000090dfffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at 2080 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 2060 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 2040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 2020 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at 901c4000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d3) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: 90000000-900fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FR (ICH6/ICH6R) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich, intel-rng

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 20b0 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FW (ICH6/ICH6W) SATA Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 20c8 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 20ec [size=4]
    I/O ports at 20c0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 20e8 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 20a0 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

05:01.0 Communication controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. HSF 56k Data/Fax Modem
    Subsystem: Conexant Systems, Inc. Device 2000
    Flags: bus master, fast Back2Back, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 11
    Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    I/O ports at 1040 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

05:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller (rev 61) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, fast Back2Back, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    Memory at 90011000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire-ohci

05:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 4037
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 20
    Memory at 90010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=64]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e100
    Kernel modules: e100
```

myersg@Ubuntu-Gateway:~$ ls -l /dev/snd/

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Feb 11 22:13 by-path
crw-rw---T+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Feb 11 22:13 controlC0
crw-rw---T+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Feb 11 22:13 hwC0D2
crw-rw---T+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Feb 11 22:13 seq
crw-rw---T+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Feb 11 22:13 timer
```

myersg@Ubuntu-Gateway:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0x901c0000 irq 44
```

Here is my file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
    # autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

Comment: Please show the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`.

Comment: just did, look at it again.

Comment: That's funny, the driver does not recognize your HDA controller. What is the output of "lspci -v" for the HDA controller? Are there any error messages in the system log when you (re)load the snd-hda-intel driver?

Comment: Just added it.  you can review it.

Comment: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0acb2f3723a9dda3b2c7162d7428d555e1413c65

Comment: Possible duplicate - see my answer here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/264272/no-sound-output-msi-k8n-neo4-ck804-ac97/274381#274381

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add the following line at the end of the file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=3stack
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

From the `alsa-info` output:

```
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x40000000: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
Pin Default 0x00000000: [Jack] Line Out at Ext N/A
```

Your BIOS has configured all the I/O pins as "not connected".
Therefore, the driver ignores them.

Try a BIOS update.

If that doesn't work (or exist), you have to find out which pins are actually connected to which input/output, compute the correct pin configuration bits for those from the HDA specification, and write them to the `/sys/class/sound/hwC0D2/user_pin_configs` file.

Comment: how would I ago about doing a bios update?

Comment: Check whether [this BIOS](http://support.gateway.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=5&modelId=2597) is newer. The update process should be explained in the manual.

Comment: This is what I have now:Ag91510j.15a.0816.2005.0214.1818

Comment: what one do I update to? and how do I do it, using ubuntu?

Comment: You already have that BIOS version. (And the update would require Windows anyway.)